# What is the difference between "Already up-to-date." and "Current branch master is up to date."

Tags: git, github

Why does git give different responses to `git pull`?

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\django-cms> git pull
Already up-to-date.

(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\dk> git pull
Current branch master is up to date.
```

Both repos come from github, and I'm on the master branch in both repos:

```
(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\django-cms> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

(dev) go|c:\srv\lib\dk> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [t/t3406-rebase-message.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/t/t3406-rebase-message.sh#L33-L35) or [`git-rebase.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/35f6318d44379452d8d33e880d8df0267b4a0cd0/git-rebase.sh#L571-L590), the second message (`Current branch master is up to date.`) occurs during a rebase.

> Check if we are already based on `$onto` with linear history

It is possible your second repo is configure to always rebase on pull.

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

The first message (`Already up-to-date`) occurs when there is [nothing to *merge*](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eda7eebe6f4c326be30deb6924d4aab213e74d4c/builtin/merge.c#L1360-L1367) (since pull is by default a fetch + a merge).